# SSH key management

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm looking for a script or program to facilitate the following scenario:

In our home network, there are lots of devices I can SSH in (all running a flavour of Linux). There are mobile phones, VCRs, our router, various laptops, NAS, VPS and so on, some 20 devices altogether.

I'm looking for a tool that lets me manage my family member's SSH keys on the devices easily, i.e.

- Display whose public key is on which account on which device
- Let me easily replace an old key with a new one across all devices
- Install a new key across several devices

We don't have LDAP or NIS in place, because I don't have root on all devices (phones, VPS).

I believe that this is a common problem / scenario that already has multiple solutions, but I was unable to find suitable stuff on the internet.
*Config management* tools (puppet, chef, …) seem like to much overhead, although I haven't looked into them yet. *Manually scripting something* would be my last resort, but as stated above, I'm sure there are already tools out there.

I prefer commandline tools (perhaps curses-based), but I'd also happily run any other stuff, be it Python, Perl or Ruby scripts, a Rails or GNOME app, whatever.

Comment: After searching the net high and low and not finding anything, here's a draft: https://github.com/jniggemann/sskm

Answer (score 2):

Since you probably will distribute the SSH public keys via SSH, you will either need to rely on previously installed public keys or passwords.

So I suggest to use OpenSSH's `ssh-copy-id` tool for copying keys to remote systems, either directly or as backend for a to-be-written tool. It though doesn't do much than adding keys. It can't remove keys as far as I know.

There are some other implementations of similar tools, e.g. [ESR's ssh-installkeys](http://www.catb.org/~esr/ssh-installkeys/) or [pushkey](https://github.com/abiheiri/pushkey), but none of them seem to be able to list or remove keys from remote systems.

Comment: Yes, I thought of writing the initial pubkey via ssh using a password.

Your last phrase describes the shortcomings of those tools and the reason why I look for something different.